# Java: Hibernate Filter & FilterDefs Annotation

Tags: java, security, hibernate, spring, acl

I would like to clarify few finding.

1. It's true when define Filter, it's required to define FilterDefs?
   There's scenario that i does't required any parameter, because the filter it's self is sufficient.
   eg: filterName="filter1" condition="ID in (select id from table1"), filterName="filter2" condition="ID in (select id from table2)"
2. It's true when define a Filter, filter name should not contain dot "." character?
   When I define a class name as filterName, hibernate can't find FilterDefs
   eg: filterName="org.my.company.Class1" condition="ID in (select id from table1")
3. Is the following condition is correct:
   filterName="filter3" condition="ID in (select id from table1 where column1 like '%:param1%')"

question: What I'm tries to do?

Answer: I'm using Spring ACL and I want to query all granted entity for given sid. I had create Spring ACL entity object.
My domain and sid is my ACL session query parameter. 
Then I'm using my domain name as a filter name so that a would easily enable the required filter
eg: session.enableFilter(myclass.getCanonicalName());
session.createQuery("select count(distinct aoi.id) from AclObjectIdentity aoi join aoi.entries e where ......"

Thanks